# Quickly Updating OpenGL Textures

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

The Android app I'm developing needs to render a few large bitmaps that are being updated continuously every frame. For the past year I rendered them through SurfaceView and Canvas, but now with the huge screen size of the Galaxy Nexus, drawing a large bitmap is extremely slow.

I'm making attempts to swap the rendering to openGL, but I can't update the textures fast enough each frame. At the moment I'm using glTexSubImage2d() to copy the bitmap data into a texture every frame, but this is much too slow. I've searched around a bit and apparently [glCopyTexSubImage is somewhat faster](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/117067-gltexsubimage-too-slow/), but the Android implementation doesn't accept a data parameter.

Any suggestions how I might be able to render dynamic textures without lag?

Comment: I found a source that claims calling texImage2d and then rendering in the same frame stalls the GPU, and recommends double buffering. However, I'm not really sure how double buffering would help.

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/2e9a8332d6378918

Comment: What kind of updates you're doing on Bitmaps? It can't be anything very big changes if you're able to update Bitmaps for every frame, right?

Comment: Im not trying to answer a question with a question but Im just currious.....are you calling your opengl using java or c/c++?

Comment: Java, though the gl methods I'm using should just call the native methods.

Comment: It's a photo editing app, so it can be anything from drawing a line diagonally across the screen, or blurring a portion, or cutting a selection out of a layer. The bitmap operations are quick. Problem is they have to be done on the bitmap objects as I use features of the Canvas object.

Comment: I see. Have you considered using some sort of layering? You could upload one 'base' texture to OpenGL and do e.g line drawing on top of it, using transparent SurfaceView for example, and once user is done with line drawing, update texture only then?

Comment: They should but Ive read on here and a couple places that using opengl through java isnt as fast as just using c/c++ because of the java bindings.....I dont know if this is true or not but Ive been looking into doing all my opengl in c++. It might be possible that if you did all the opengl stuff natively that your textures might not lag.

Comment: The difficulty is that the layer above it must be drawn as well. SurfaceView is too slow rendering a large bitmap on the Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: Have you tried disabling hardware acceleration altogether? While I have none experience on ICS yet it might be the case you end up uploading new updated Bitmap to GPU on every draw as hinted here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#tips .

Comment: Hey! That fixed the problem for surface view at least. Doesn't necessarily answer the question, but solves the difficulties I was having. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this answers your question, but the way I'm doing it is I have a framebuffer allocated in C/C++ and pass this to java via ByteBuffer (jni->NewDirectByteBuffer()). I'm using this as a texture and it works fast and fine. Then, I can modify this framebuffer directly in C/C++ and the changes are visible immedialty after render is performed on the OpenGL sufrace. I'm currently having problems with ICS Galaxy Nexus, as it does not apply the texture correctly if the texture exceeds 2048x2048 pixels. I'm assuming the error is related to hardware constrains of the device, but I am still doing some testing.

Comment: This sounds extremely interesting. I will look into it. Do you have more information on how you got it working? (For instance how you can use a bytebuffer as an openGL texture) Thanks!

Comment: OpenGL methods take ByteBuffer (or CharBuffer) as a parameter. For instance, `gl.glTexSubImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, textureWidth, textureHeight, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, charBuffer);`. You can pass this buffer from C/C++ to Java via `jni->NewDirectByteBuffer()` method.